# Making Temporary UI like Modal in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I want to to use modal UI View like in that design :http://www.pinterest.com/pin/31103053650794607/

Is it possible to use in iOS without adding extra library ?

Regards ,

Onder

Comment: u can make your own, its very simple one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use ModalViewController:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html

Comment: the link that you have given :  "iPhone apps, presented views always cover the visible portion of the window". I want it like ipad style , the link that i gave t on my question ot

Comment: "iPhone apps, presented views always cover the visible portion of the window" I know that ! What i really want to do is, making modal is just like an ipad. Showing modal in same time current Viewcontroller visible is active.